# pip skipping upgrade, says requirement already satisfied when it is not satisfied

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, package, package-managers

Here's the output of a pip install --upgrade:

```
[vagrant@cclab8-ht-esx-11 f5]$ sudo pip install f5-icontrol-rest --upgrade
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://apds-web1.noc.bluecoatcloud.com/symc_pypi/symc_pypi_server.wsgi
Collecting f5-icontrol-rest
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/44/91979de0a81253d025a0814f16f53df46d3ed3edd5b9fd7181f28a9dd0bb/f5-icontrol-rest-1.3.13.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.5.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from f5-icontrol-rest) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest) (2018.11.29)
Building wheels for collected packages: f5-icontrol-rest
  Building wheel for f5-icontrol-rest (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/12/43/4c/9c3051759105429cd633ed53ece367db44b082fce01c28db46
Successfully built f5-icontrol-rest
Installing collected packages: f5-icontrol-rest
  Found existing installation: f5-icontrol-rest 1.3.12
    Uninstalling f5-icontrol-rest-1.3.12:
      Successfully uninstalled f5-icontrol-rest-1.3.12
Successfully installed f5-icontrol-rest-1.3.13
You are using pip version 19.0.2, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The issue is that my system requests package is version 2.21.0, and 2.21.0 is not greater than or equal to 2.5.0, yet pip says that the requirement is satisfied.

I do not understand this line:

```
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.5.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from f5-icontrol-rest) (2.21.0)
```

Does anyone understand why the requirement is satisfied? Why was requests not upgraded?

Comment: `2.21.0` is greater than `2.5.0` (by `0.16.0`).

Comment: It is greater than.  "2.21.0 is greater than 2.5.0" by 16versions

Comment: Ah, i'm dumb. I was thinking 2.21 !>= 2.50. decimals.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, 2.5.0 isn't the same as 2.50.0.